# Set of Lists with wildcarded generic as a parameter in method

Tags: java, generics

I need to pass a Set of Lists of some objects (with different types) into a function, but it doesn't work. Could somebody fix a problem?
Code example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = Set.of("1");
        print(set); //ok

        Set<List<String>> setOfList = Set.of(List.of("1"));
        print2(setOfList); //doesn't work
    }

    static void print(Set<? extends CharSequence> set) {
        System.out.println(set);
    }

    private static void print2(Set<List<? extends CharSequence>> setOfList) {
        System.out.println(setOfList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an upper bound to the set elements also:

```
Set<? extends List<? extends CharSequence>>
```

The reason is that you can add any `List<? extends CharSequence>` to a `Set<List<? extends CharSequence>>`. For example, you could add a [`List<StringBuilder>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
private static void print2(Set<List<? extends CharSequence>> setOfList) {
    setOfList.add(List.of(new StringBuilder());
}
```

If you were allowed to call the method from `main`, you would get a `ClassCastException` if you then did something like this:

```
Set<List<String>> setOfList = Set.of(List.of("1"));
print2(setOfList); // pretend it works...

for (List<String> list : setOfList) {
  String s = list.get(0);  // ClassCastException, it's a CharBuffer.
}
```

By making it `Set<? extends List<? extends CharSequence>>`, you can't add anything (except literal `null`) to the `Set`.